# how to resolve java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Tags: java, php, android

I m making an application which should upload file from sd card to php server for further processing but when i try to upload my logcat shows the following error: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out). My java code is as below.

```
package de.smsbackup;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import de.smsbackup.SMSList;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Uploader extends Activity {

private String Tag = "UPLOADER";
private String urlString = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/admin/admin/uploadtest.php";
HttpURLConnection conn;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.upload_sms_file);

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()  
    .detectDiskReads()  
    .detectDiskWrites()  
    .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems  
    .penaltyLog()  
    .build());  
   StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()  
    .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()  
    .detectLeakedClosableObjects()  
    .penaltyLog()  
    .penaltyDeath()  
    .build()); 
    String exsistingFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/SMSBackup.txt";

    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    try {
        // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST

        Log.e(Tag, "Inside second Method");

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                exsistingFileName));

        // open a URL connection to the Servlet

        URL url = new URL(urlString);

        // Open a HTTP connection to the URL

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        // Allow Outputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        // Don't use a cached copy.
        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        // Use a post method.
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: post-data; name=uploadedfile;filename="
                        + exsistingFileName + "" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        Log.e(Tag, "Headers are written");

        // create a buffer of maximum size

        int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        int maxBufferSize = 1000;
        // int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesAvailable];

        // read file and write it into form...

        int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bytesAvailable = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);
        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...

        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // close streams
        Log.e(Tag, "File is written");
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Log.e(Tag, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }

    catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e(Tag, "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
    }


    try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn
                .getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.e("Dialoge Box", "Message: " + line);
        }
        rd.close();

    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        Log.e("Note Pad", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
    }
}
}
```

My PHP file is as below:

```
<?php
// Where the file is going to be placed 
 $target_path = "admin/";

 /* Add the original filename to our target path.  
  Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
 $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
  echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
  " has been uploaded";
  chmod ("uploads/".basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']), 0644);
} else{
 echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
 echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
 echo "target_path: " .$target_path;
}
?>
```

Please could any one tell me ASAP that where i m wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You are shure, that the PHP-Server is reachable from the Application? ETIMEDOUT means, that after 5(?)  retries no connection could be established. Try to ping the targeted Host, and make shure that the targeted webserver listens also to port 8080.

Comment: 10.0.2.2 sounds like an internal IP address. Is your device on the same network, as in connected through Wi-Fi rather than a cell network?

Comment: I m using an emulator with eclipse. When i try to ping at my machine the 10.0.2.2 it gives me request timed out error. then what should i do or what should is use instead of 10.0.2.2 in case of emulator?

Answer (score -1):

I think that happening because you deal with IP. Try using domain name.